# Make layer only be shown over black color

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Here's my problem: I want to make some brush strokes for a motion graphic video I'm working on. I want them to be plain, with no texture rather than a gradient. 
I have the figure of the brush drawn in black over a transparent layer and in the upper oneI have the gradient ready to go.

I want to "merge" both layers but without actually merging them nor having to cut out some area of the gradient. I want to draw a stroke and have it filled with the gradient.

I don't know if this is possible or how could this be done.

Any help is higly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly there are (at least) two ways to do this.

1. If your brush strokes are drawn on a transparent layer, you can use a **Clipping Mask**:

   - Place the gradient layer right above the stroke layer.
   - Hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and left click to use the brush layer as a clipping mask for the gradient.
     [image]
2. If your stroke layer has white background, you can use a **Layer Mask**:

   - Select the stroke layer.
   - Press <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select all.
   - Press <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy to clipboard.
   - Turn off the stroke layer.
   - Select the gradient layer.
   - Click the *Add layer mask* button in the *Layers* panel.
   - Hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and left click the mask to enter it.
   - Press <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to paste from clipboard.
   - Press <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to deselect all.
   - Press <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to invert the mask.
   - Click the gradient layer icon to leave the mask.
   - Now you can paint in the layer mask.
     [image]

These two methods are *essential* for image editing in Photoshop. They can be used for numerous different tasks.

Comment: that was exactly what I was searching for!